# "Recently Active" linked questions updates incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-deferred, linked-questions

When there are too many linked questions to fit in the sidebar, it shows a link to "see more linked questions...". Clicking on this link takes you to a front-page type showing only the linked questions. You can then use the tabs to sort by "active" to show the most recently active linked questions.

However, the gray popup that appears when new questions are posted shows up for **any** recent activity, not just activity on the linked questions. Clicking through then updates the list, appending more questions to the top of the list, regardless of whether or not they're linked to the question at hand.

To reproduce:

- Go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/208220?sort=active
- Wait for activity

Screenshots:

[image: showing "6 questions with new activity"]
[image: clicked through to show new activity]

Now obviously this isn't a show-stopper, but I thought it might be worth mentioning.

---

**Update June 2020**

This is still relevant.

[image: Screenshot from Scifi.SE, showing a "1 question with new activity" banner on a linked questions page]

While sitting on the "linked questions" page for a specific question - in the above screenshot, [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/18129?sort=newest) - and sorted by newest, when a new question is *asked* the "1 question with new activity" banner will show up, even if that new question does not link back to the question that you were on.

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237227/x-questions-with-new-activity-is-wrongfully-showing-in-linked-questions-list).

Comment: Coming back to this: it's on our list to investigate more. Better seven years late than never? Will update here with more once we get to it.

Comment: @JonChan: Any updates, another year and a half later? :P