# "x questions with new activity" is wrongfully showing in linked questions list

Tags: bug, live-refresh, linked-questions

When a question got many other questions linked from/to it, there is a special page showing list of all those questions, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/184642?sort=active

I just noticed while leaving it open, that the live refresh is active in there and showing "x questions with new activity" whenever there is new activity, even if in a question not linked to/from the original question.

I think the live refresh should be disabled while in that view, or filtered to load only questions actually being linked.

Comment: Some screenshot are shown here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266287/unexpected-behavior-of-linked-questions-when-sorted-by-recent-activity

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209174/recently-active-linked-questions-updates-incorrectly). (Perhaps this can be considered a duplicate?)

Comment: Great find @Martin guess I'm good at finding dupes of others, not myself. :)

Comment: I found it by accident. It was shown among related questions when I was asking about something completely different.