# Unexpected behavior of linked questions when sorted by recent activity

Tags: bug, live-refresh, linked-questions, active

For any question I can view questions linked from/to it by from the url of the form: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/id` where id stands for the number of question. If some question has many linked posts, then this link is even available - by clicking on "see more linked questions..." at the bottom of linked questions list.

When I get the list of linked questions, I can choose from the tabs: hot, newest, votes, active, unanswered. I occasionally use this list ordered by recent activity if I am curious about something like this: Why were there recently upvotes on this relatively old post of mine? Did somebody link to it recently? Was something interesting related to this  topic posted recently?

Today I noticed that when I left the list open in one tab, and did something in another one, the number indicating new questions appeared.  It seemed a bit surprising that several posts would be linked to quite old post in such a short period. When I got back to this tab, I saw the gray banner: "3 questions with new activity". After clicking on it, new questions appeared on list. (It seems to be the recently active question on the given site.) After refreshing the page, this new questions disappeared and only questions which are really linked to the original one were shown again.

I should add that probably people will be using links like this very seldom and it can be corrected by refreshing the displayed page, so it is definitely not much of a problem. But I guess it is still a bug worth reporting.

---

I will add screenshots showing this behavior on this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/213639?sort=active (This is where I observed it. I tried this both in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.)

Here is what I saw after coming back to the tab:

[image: the first screenshot]

Here is screenshot after clicking on the gray banner:

[image: the second screenshot]

After refreshing the page it all went back to normal.

When I tried the same thing with two questions from the same site opened in two tabs (namely [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/123097?sort=active) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/129598?sort=active)) I noticed that the same questions appeared in the list. <s>I do not know why, but in this case it took much longer time before I saw this happening. I do not know whether this might depend on the size of the site, or on what I was doing in other tabs, or something else. But for the questions I tried, it seems to take much longer on meta.SE than on math.SE.</s> Based on what I tried so far, it seems that questions which are shown are the recently active questions of the site. In the other words, if I wait a bit, the beginning of the pages https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/123097?sort=active (replace any question id here) and will become the same.

[image: the first screenshot on meta.SE]
[image: the second screenshot on meta.SE]

Comment: Now I found an older post reporting the same bug: [“x questions with new activity” is wrongfully showing in linked questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237227/x-questions-with-new-activity-is-wrongfully-showing-in-linked-questions-list). (I did not find it when posting my question.) So my post should be closed as a duplicate of that one. (Or deleted entirely? Although I think that duplicates might be useful - if somebody searches for this question, they might find one of the duplicates depending on the keywords they search for.)