# Adding a bounty should not change the license of a post

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, licensing

I found a minor bug, and after a search here on Meta.SE, I discovered that it had been [reported all the way back in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209174/294691). To draw a bit of attention to it, I then added a bounty to the post.

The past hadn't been edited in a while, so the license was CC-by-SA 3.0 (and that was confirmed in the timeline of the post). However, went I went to share the link, the share popout told me that it had a license of 4.0. Apparently, my bounty had caused the license to update - which shouldn't happen, since I didn't edit the text in any way. (I have since edited the post, but there are screenshots below.)

---

> On Meta a [bug I did find](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209174/294691)
> That no-one had paid any mind
> I then took a step
> And gave up some rep
> For a bug I had found - the same kind
>
> Then, when I went on to "share"
> The popup appeared with a flair
> With a license CC
> That I plainly could see
> Should never have really been there.
>
> For the post was historic and old
> On the timeline, "3.0" showed there bold
> But the share told me four
> To the bounty eyes tore
> And the truth so at last had been told.

[image: Share button showing a 4.0 license]

> My bounty, to show this bug's plight
> Has updated the licensing right
> Now this should not be
> 'Tis plain, we can see —
> The content has not changed in sight

[image: The post timeline, showing a 4.0 CC license at the top but no revisions with a 4.0 license]

Comment: Why do you want to make a poem?

Comment: @CulverKwan - it's a nod to Yaakov Ellis's [recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348883/294691) [haiku](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348816/294691) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348523/294691). :)

Comment: @Mithical now would be a great time to add that to the meme repository, if it hasnt already.

Comment: @Luuklag it's time to add to / the meme repository / unless it's in there

Comment: @VLAZ there is this one, but not sure: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/32877

Comment: @Luuklag the page is not found / I get an error message / this is a haiku

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32877/361484 @VLAZ

Comment: This task I now assume, I will make my incursion. When the dust has settled, this post will show the proper version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is fixed. It was happening due to a logic error in calculating the license for specific posts (which due to their details were not caught in the initial backfill).

To honor this occasion and [the author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349563/51) of the post above, I offer this Sonnet in [Shakespearean form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare%27s_sonnets#Form_and_structure_of_the_sonnets).

> A user thought to pay a just reward,
>
> by adding bounty payment on a post,
>
> and after setting what they could afford,
>
> they clicked start and sent it on to the host.
>
> Now off to share the link with Tavern crowd,
>
> did Mithical set out at once with glee,
>
> and what they saw made them stop feeling proud,
>
> 'cause printed there was four instead of three.
>
> Quick on to Meta to report the case,
>
> came our brave hero armed with prose and rhyme,
>
> and when I saw it — turned red in my face,
>
> seeking to repro' and fix in no time.
>
> I now announce the squashing of the bug,
>
> it's now forgotten — swept under the rug.

Comment: Very nice job. :D

Comment: May the effort that this took be less than or equal to the joy you experience from sharing it